# How to reproduce such image schematics/graphs?

Tags: python, latex, gimp

I would like to reproduce this schematic of a microscope and the graphs below it, but I can´t recognize with which software it has been produced. Do you think it has been programmed or drawn as vectors in some graphic  software?

I am mostly concerned on how the trajectory of ion and electrons (red and blue lines) have been produced.

Any suggestion?

Thank you!

[image: schematic + graphs]

Comment: There are many ways this could have been done. You could draw it with inkscape and similar programs or you could use TikZ

Comment: What about the trajectories? How would be possible to program a trajectory in those programs?

Comment: They can be done using Bézier curves

Answer (score 2):

You could use Bézier curves to draw the trajectories, e.g. a quick and dirty sketch:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red] (-1.7286,5.6002) .. controls (-1.7286,5.6002) and (2.5610,5.3482) .. (4.6987,4.7064) .. controls (4.9925,4.6182) and (4.9940,4.4655) .. (4.9940,4.4655);
\draw[blue] (4.9940,4.4655) .. controls (4.9940,4.4655) and (4.8360,3.8956) .. (4.7375,3.8981) .. controls (4.6429,3.9005) and (4.6456,4.5949) .. (4.7064,4.5898) .. controls (4.8256,4.5798) and (4.7803,3.9125) .. (5.0328,3.9059) .. controls (5.2924,3.8992) and (5.4064,4.6032) .. (5.7168,4.6054) .. controls (6.0692,4.6079) and (6.3260,3.9225) .. (6.7349,3.9215) .. controls (7.2980,3.9200) and (7.6279,4.5942) .. (8.1493,4.5898) .. controls (8.4153,4.5876) and (8.8194,4.2087) .. (9.1182,4.0402) .. controls (9.4170,3.8718) and (9.5172,3.9137) .. (9.5172,3.9137);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you!